# OffsetDateTime value is changed when retrieved from the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, timezone, offsetdatetime

I am using a table from `MS SQL` database and developed a `GET API` using `Spring Boot`, to retrieve all the data from that table.
Here the table contains a column of type `datetimeoffset(7)`.

I have data member `OffsetDateTime updatedDate` inside my Entity, used to map `datetimeoffset` column from the DB

Now, when I get the API response, I see the `updatedDate` value (**2021-06-17T05:37:40.1938687+05:30**) is different from actual database value (**2021-06-16 19:07:40.1938687 -05:00**).

I explored web to find some help and tried few solutions similar to [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653797/1668225), however I did not see any positive results.

Any help would be really appreciable, thanks!

PS. `Spring Boot` version: `2.3.1.RELEASE`

Answer (score 1):

These two values represent exactly the same point at timeline. They are just represented in different time zones: database uses [EST](https://www.utctime.net/est-time-now) and `Spring` app uses [IST Indian](https://www.utctime.net/ist-indian-time-now). When we convert them to GMT they will look the same:

```
String[] dates = {"2021-06-17T05:37:40.1938687 +05:30", "2021-06-16T19:07:40.1938687 -05:00"};
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.n XXX")
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
Arrays.stream(dates)
        .map(date -> formatter.format(OffsetDateTime.parse(date, formatter)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Above code prints:

```
2021-06-17T00:07:40.1938687 Z
2021-06-17T00:07:40.1938687 Z
```

If you want to keep original representation you need to instruct to use `EST` timezone instead of default or system one. Try to set: [spring.jackson.time-zone](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.json.spring.jackson.time-zone) property in configuration file:

> Time zone used when formatting dates. For instance,
> "America/Los_Angeles" or "GMT+10".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the spring.jackson.time-zone property in application.properties with value as GMT-5, however I still see the same result.
Do I need to do any other additional jackson related configuation apart from the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653455/date-timezone-with-spring-boot-and-jackson/46653797#46653797

Comment: @Vishal, Which version of `Jackson` do you use? Did you create your own instance of `ObjectMapper` or you use common one created by `Spring`? How does it work when you create a test controller and return new instance of `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: I am using ```Jackson``` version as ```2.11.0``` and yes I have provided customised instance of ObjectMapper where in I am explicitly disabling ```WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS``` and ```ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE```
When I return a new instance of ```OffsetDateTime```, I see its having ```IST``` zone

Comment: Hi Michal, btw when I send ```OffsetDateTime``` instance with different ZoneOffset, I see the new zone in API response correctly. 
For example, ```OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now();
now = now.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOddset.of("-05:30");
return now;```
I need jackson to do this for me.

Comment: @Vishal, try also to check how `OffsetDateTime` looks like when it is loaded from database. Do you use `Hibernate` or any other `ORM`? Take a look at [Hibernate not correctly storing ZonedDateTime as datetimeoffset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808423/hibernate-not-correctly-storing-zoneddatetime-as-datetimeoffset-in-sql-server)

Comment: even after trying above, I still on the same page

Answer (score 1):

> Now, when I get the API response, I see the updatedDate value
> (2021-06-17T05:37:40.1938687+05:30) is different from actual database
> value (2021-06-16 19:07:40.1938687 -05:00).

No, both the Date-Time represent the same instant/moment.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Instant.parse("2021-06-17T05:37:40.1938687+05:30"));
        System.out.println(Instant.parse("2021-06-16T19:07:40.1938687-05:00"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-17T00:07:40.193868700Z
2021-06-17T00:07:40.193868700Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/VaZ2eQ)

### You can convert one into another

Using [`OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-), you can convert one into another.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odtFromResponse = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-06-17T05:37:40.1938687+05:30");

        OffsetDateTime odtDesired = odtFromResponse.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
        System.out.println(odtDesired);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-16T19:07:40.193868700-05:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/uaAxz7)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Yes, I can understand the dates are exact equal, just the timezone is different. I do not want jackson to convert date from EST to IST, for which I did set the configuration (mentioned in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653455/date-timezone-with-spring-boot-and-jackson/46653797#46653797). However I still see the date retrieved contains IST time zone, not EST

Comment: @Vishal - Try `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSXXX", timezone="America/Chicago")
OffsetDateTime updatedDate` and let me know if it solved your problem. Change the timezone as per your DB server's timezone.

Comment: Hi Arvind, after doing suggested changes, I still see the same timezone. Do I need to  stop providing custom implementation of ObjectMapper?

JFYI, ```OffsetDateTime``` member is inside ```@Entity``` where I have used ```@JsonFormat``` annotation.

Comment: @Vishal - From your other comment I noticed that you have already implemented a custom `ObjectMapper`. By any chance, did you try the suggestion in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451939/jackson-offsetdatetime-serialization-z-instead-of-0000-timezone#comment110001441_60454450)?

Comment: Hi Arvind, I have already tried this but no luck.
One solution to my problem is, to make JVM timezone and DB timezone the same For instance, using JVM argument ```-Duser.timezone=US/Central```. This helps to solve this issue. However, in my case I do not want to make Spring Boot application dependent on timezone of the Database.